# Make js functions execute one after another

Tags: javascript, ajax, synchronization

Note : **No jQuery**

I have four functions and I want to call them one after another ie. call a function after the previously called function is executed (in core js, not jquery). I tried searching in the internet but I could not find a satisfied answer. Here is what I've done so far :

```
function func1() {
    noAjaxCall.click();
    return true;
}

function func2() {
    ajaxCall.click();           <--------- sending an ajax request
    return true;
}

function func3() {
    noAjaxCall.click();
    return true;
}

function func4() {
    //anything here
}

if(func1())
    if(func2())
        if(func3())
            func4();
```

What happens is that, `func3` is not called. Why this happens and any work around to this?

Thanks!

Comment: From just triggering a click, there's not much to wait for, you should call the actual function and return a promise instead of triggering the click, or you could hack it and hook into global ajax events if you're using a library like jQuery.

Comment: yeahm I noticed that; and I'm not using jQuery here!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you're not doing what you expect.
The AjaxCall is not really done when func3 will be called, cause... it's asynchronous.

I prefere you find the real solution (what you really wanna do) than trying to solve this problem.

Could you give the real goal you try to achieve?

**edit**

Let's imagime the handle on 'click' for ajaxCall. I know u don't have jQuery on the app but I create what I know.

```
function requester(){
    //do some asyn work
    $.ajax({ //...
        success: function() {
            //HERE call the other functions
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: ok, asking the work around is beyond the scope of the original question! Thanks :)

Comment: I've edited but you should read about asynchronous callback in JS :)